# C++ Derive from template class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to create a subclass of the following:

```
template <
   class THandler,
   class ThreadModel     = CComSingleThreadModel,
   class TagReplacerType = CHtmlTagReplacer< THandler >
>
class CRequestHandlerT :
   public TagReplacerType,
   public CComObjectRootEx< ThreadModel >,
   public IRequestHandlerImpl< THandler >
```

The class above works perfectly if used as follows:

```
class Cmy_form : public CRequestHandlerT<Cmy_form>
```

But I am trying to create a subclass (to extend CRequestHandlerT functionality by adding an additional member function):

```
class Cmybase_form : public CRequestHandlerT<Cmybase_form> {...};

class Cmy_form : public Cmybase_form {...};    // builds but runtime error
```

1. Am I subclassing **Cmybase_form** properly?
2. Am I using the subclass **Cmy_form** correct?

Comment: It is going to be pretty hard to debug without more code or information about the error that is occurring.

Comment: Ben, but what about the syntax to Cmybase_form? Does it look like I am deriving incorrectly?  My goal is to add a member function to Cmybase_form and derive from it instead of from CRequestHandlerT.

Comment: Do you know why you need the CRTP? It looks like `CRequestHandlerT<T>` will be calling functions of T. So, that leads to a big difference between the two forms of `Cmy_form` shown above. If all the functions of `T` needed by `CRequestHandlerT` are virtual, you should be good I think. Do you have any idea when the runtime error happens? Perhaps it is at destruction of `Cmy_form` because it doesn't have a virtual destructor?

Comment: Pradham, can you give me an example of how you would subclass CRequestHandlerT? I am very confused.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran does this member function you want to add to `Cmybase_form` depend on `CRequestHandlerT`? In other words, can you do `class Cmybase_form`. And `class Cmy_form : public Cmybase_form, CRequestHandlerT<Cmy_form>`?

Comment: @Pradhan, yes it does depend on CRequestHandlerT. I wanted to derive and create Cmybase_form which I would add the member function to and use Cmybase_form instead of CRequestHandlerT.

Comment: @Pradhan, my new method would depend heavily on CRequestHandlerT, and because of this, I don't think multiple inheritance or composition would not work for me.

Comment: Too difficult to guess what you're trying to do _and_ intuit how it is not working. It would be much better to have a minimal compiling example of code that produces the runtime error. Maybe take the actual compiling code (which you have, right?) and delete as much as you can, but not so much that it doesn't compile or you no longer see the same runtime error.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran your subclassing is OK, the error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrote some code based on my understanding and it is working fine. Please let me know if I have misunderstood your requirement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class tbase {
    public:
    tbase () {}
    ~tbase () {}
    virtual bool my_print (T value) 
    {
        cout << "Value passed is: " << value << endl;
    }

    virtual void print ()
    {
        cout << "TBASE" << endl;
    }
};


template <class T>
class mbase : public tbase<T>
{
    public:
    mbase ()
        : tbase<T>()
    {}

    virtual void print ()
    {
        cout << "MBASE" << endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
class child : public mbase <T>
{
    public:
    child ()
        : mbase<T> ()
    {}

    virtual void print ()
    {
        cout << "CHILD" << endl;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    tbase <int> * b = new child<int>;
    b->print();
    b->my_print( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Please revert back if it does not satisfy your requirement. We will work out on that.